# How to convert a MySql selection into an string? C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Convert MySQL Select to an String. To take the ip

```
MySqlCommand o = connection.CreateCommand();
o.CommandText = "SELECT Ip FROM Sma.Serv WHERE Id=1";
MySqlDataReader r = o.ExecuteReader();
PingReply rep1 = serv.Send("print Ip from DataBase Here", 1000);
```

Comment: I am struggling to figure out what you want here. What, specifically, is your question?

Comment: Print "Ip" in `PingReply rep1 = serv.Send("print Ip from DataBase Here", 1000);`

Comment: What is your Question

Comment: Convert MySQL Select to an String. To take the ip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
o.CommandText = "SELECT Ip FROM Sma.Serv WHERE Id=1";
MySqlDataReader r = o.ExecuteReader();
string _ip;
```

then you expect 1 result or 0, you can use an 'if'

```
if(r.Read())
{
    _ip = r[0].ToString();
}
```

if you may have more than 1 result you have to use a while loop

```
while(r.Read())
{
     _ip = r[0].ToString();
}
```

in this case, and if you wan't to do something only if your request return one ip, you can add a counter in you loop while

```
int i = 0;
while(r.Read())
{
     _ip = r[0].ToString();
     i++;
}
if(i==1)
{
     // do your stuff
}
else {//do another stuff}
```

and don't forget to close the datareader after!!!

```
r.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked :)

I didn't know I had to close MySqlDataReader.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the example [here on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx)

And here is an example using similar code to what you've written above to retrieve the **first** records ip via the `GetString` method:

```
o.CommandText = "SELECT Ip FROM Sma.Serv WHERE Id=1";
MySqlDataReader r = o.ExecuteReader();
if (r.HasRows)
{
    r.Read();
    var firstRecordIp = r.GetString(0);
}
```

Please note, you could also use a `DataAdapter` to `fill` the data to a `DataTable`.

Comment: Runs and takes the Ip of the database, then arises mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
o.CommandText = "SELECT Ip FROM Sma.Serv WHERE Id=1";
MySqlDataReader r = o.ExecuteReader();
string _ip;
while(r.Read())
{
   _ip = r["Ip"].ToString();
}
if(_ip != "")
{
  //do your task
}
```